# transferring Principal from EJBContext to Spring SecurityContext

Tags: spring, security, ejb

I'm using springsecurity to protect some EJB methods deployed on jBoss 5.1.0.

I'm looking for a nice way to transfer the `java.security.Principal` retrieved from the [EJBContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html), by calling `getPrincipal()`, to the Spring [SecurityContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html).

I wouldn't like to give up the springsecurity schema, just need to set the `Principal` before the execution of the [MethodSecurityInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/aopalliance/MethodSecurityInterceptor.html).

Any idea?

Comment: At the end I have given up with this intention. I've implemented kind of hibrid solution: JAAS+springsecurity. The client uses JAAS to be authenticated to the ejb on the sever. I've written a custom JAAS LoginModule which delegates authentication to the springsecurity code and before returning stores the Authentication object into the Spring SecurityContext. In this way my code is secured by springsecurity, so fully portable to any other container, for instances weblogic, tomcat.